# Reference error using High Chart's API. MVC 3

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, highcharts

I'm using the High Chart's API to create a line chart on my DetailsPage, after setting it up according to this tutorial, [high charts mvc](http://www.nimbo.com/blog/how-to-use-highcharts-js-with-asp-net-mvc-4/) . The problem is when I publish the site from Visual Studio, the chart doesn't show.

To debug this, I checked the page with inspect element after the site is published and came across this error:

"HighCharts is not defined" which points to this line in the ChartController,
`chart = new Highcharts.Chart({`.

Does anyone know how to fix this reference error? Or how can I debug the problem, as I seem to have followed all the relevant steps.

The High Charts bundle is defined like this in the bundle config class:

```
  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/highcharts").IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/Highcharts-4.0.1/js", "*.js"));
```

The bundle as its referenced in the layout.cshtml file:

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - Gesture Physio - Control Panel</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/highcharts")
```

And this is the location of the js files within the project tree:

[image: high chart location]

This is the page's mark up:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DetailsPage";
}

<h2>Progress Details Chart</h2>

@model DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts

<p>Max Range Readings</p>
@(Model)
```

And the page's controller:

```
using DotNet.Highcharts;
using DotNet.Highcharts.Enums;
using DotNet.Highcharts.Helpers;
using DotNet.Highcharts.Options;
using GesturePhysioWebClient.DAL;
using GesturePhysioWebClient.Models;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace GesturePhysioWebClient.Controllers
{
    public class ChartController : Controller
    {

        //Restrict access to non-logged in users
        [Authorize]
        public async Task<ActionResult> DetailsPage()
        {

            var mobileClient = new MobileServiceClient("https://progressreportdb.azure-mobile.net/",
               "************************"
           );
            var itemModelTable = mobileClient.GetTable<Item>();

            var result = await itemModelTable
                /*.OrderByDescending(Item => Item.Id)
                .Take(40)*/
                .ToListAsync();

            ViewBag.Message = "Patient Progress Details.";

            var yDataMaxRange = result.Select(item => Double.Parse(item.Max_Range ?? "0")).ToArray();
            var xDataDates = result.Select(item => DateTime.Parse(item.Date, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToShortDateString()).ToArray();
            //cast the y values to an object array:
            object[] yDataAsObjectArray = yDataMaxRange.Cast<object>().ToArray();


            var chart = new Highcharts("chart").
                InitChart(new Chart { DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Line })
                .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "User Max Range Readings" })
                .SetSubtitle(new Subtitle { Text = "ROM Progress" })
                .SetXAxis(new XAxis { Categories = xDataDates })
                .SetYAxis(new YAxis { Title = new YAxisTitle { Text = "Max Range Readings" } })
                .SetTooltip(new Tooltip { Enabled = true, Formatter = @"function() {return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b> <br/>' + this.x + ':' + this.y; }" })
                .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
                {
                    Line = new PlotOptionsLine
                    {
                        DataLabels = new PlotOptionsLineDataLabels
                        {
                            Enabled = true
                        },
                        EnableMouseTracking = false
                    }
                })
              .SetSeries(new[]
            {
                 new Series {Name = "Max ROM", Data = new Data(yDataAsObjectArray) }
                 //new Series { Name = "Total", Data = new Data(new object[] { 441, 441, 22, 30, 610 }) }

            });


            return View(chart);


        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the bundle to your layout file. The relevant code is below:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/highcharts")
```

You can add this to the head tag in your layout file. Also make sure that you add the jquery bundle before the highcharts bundle as mentioned in the article.

In your BundleConfig, replace your highcharts bundles to not use IncludeDirectory as shown below

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/highcharts").Include(
                 "~/Scripts/Highcharts-4.0.1/js/highcharts.js"
                    ));
```

Comment: I've already added this to my layout file, see my edit above. The reference still shows HighCharts is not defined. Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Please check if it works without using an IncludeDirectory and just a plain Include pointing to highcharts.js

Comment: Okay I'll test that now

Comment: that was the error! can you explain what the difference between the two are?

Comment: One includes all .js files in the directory and the other only a single file. My guess is that when you included all the .js files in the directory, it caused a conflict.